# Zip files corrupted when downloaded using Python 3 (not Python 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to download zip files using Python3, however each time the file is corrupted.

I think the following code worked fine in Python2, however now does not seem to work Python 3 - has there been a change between P2 and P3 that is likely to cause issues with how `shutil` works?

```
    zip_file = requests.get(zip_package_url, headers = request_headers, stream=True)
    with open(zip_file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(zip_file.raw, out_file)
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved - getting in byte format from requests, and then saving as bytes seems to work:

```
    zip_file = requests.get(zip_package_url, headers = request_headers, stream=True).content
    with open(zip_file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(zip_file)
```

Comment: what is `request_headers`?